# iPhone Accelerometer forward,back,left,right

Tags: ios, iphone, accelerometer

I would like to know how to create code that would allow me to place an iPhone flat on a surface and move it forward to get positive y value, back to get -y, left to get -x and right to get -x. The code I am using only seems to measure positive acceleration and I can not generate negative values while the phone is laid flat on surface. If I lift the phone and then tilt it to the right or left, I will get positive x and negative x and same with y but I want the same affect while leaving it on the surface and simply shifting the phone in left and right directions while keeping it facing forward without any type of turning or rotation. I am using swift but will also be happy to use object c if there is a solution.

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var currentMaxAccelX: Double = 0.0
var currentMaxAccelY: Double = 0.0
var currentMaxAccelZ: Double = 0.0

let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

@IBOutlet var accX : UILabel? = nil
@IBOutlet var accY : UILabel? = nil
@IBOutlet var accZ : UILabel? = nil

@IBOutlet var maxAccX : UILabel? = nil
@IBOutlet var maxAccY : UILabel? = nil
@IBOutlet var maxAccZ : UILabel? = nil



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1


    //[self.motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue new] withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)


    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {(accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error:NSError!)in
        self.outputAccelerationData(accelerometerData.acceleration)
        if (error != nil)
        {
            println("\(error)")
        }
    })

}



func outputAccelerationData(acceleration:CMAcceleration)
{
    // Swift does not have string formation yet
    accX?.text = NSString(format:"%.4f", acceleration.x) as String

    if fabs(acceleration.x) > fabs(currentMaxAccelX)
    {
        currentMaxAccelX = acceleration.x
    }

    accY?.text = NSString(format:"%.4f", acceleration.y) as String

    if acceleration.y > currentMaxAccelY
    {
        currentMaxAccelY = acceleration.y
    }

    accZ?.text = NSString(format:"%.4f", acceleration.z) as String

    if acceleration.z > currentMaxAccelZ
    {
        currentMaxAccelZ = acceleration.z
    }

    maxAccX?.text = NSString(format:"%.4f", currentMaxAccelX) as String
    maxAccY?.text = NSString(format:"%.4f", currentMaxAccelY) as String
    maxAccZ?.text = NSString(format:"%.4f", currentMaxAccelZ) as String

}
```

Comment: I can recommend this tutorial http://nscookbook.com/2013/03/ios-programming-recipe-19-using-core-motion-to-access-gyro-and-accelerometer/  I went by it about a year ago, and I think it should help.

Comment: This code is very similar to the code I am using. With the code in this link you still cannot differentiate between left movement as negative and right movement as positive while the phone is flat on a surface without tilting. Just about every example on the net I can find implements similar code and you can only get negative and positive values by tilting the phone and not simply shifting.